# Trouble understanding the relation between MongoDB and RocksDB

Tags: mongodb, rocksdb

As I am learning to use Parse, I came across a [announcement from parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/mongodb-rocksdb-parse/) saying they were using RocksDB and MongoDB.

Even after research, the relationship between Rocks and MongoDB is not clear cut to me, and what are the benefit to use RocksDB instead of a simple MongoDB.

As I understand it, RocksDB is a key-value store, while MongoDB is a noSQL database.

So, what is the point of adding RocksDB on MongoDB (or is it Mongo on Rocks?), and in that case, where are stored the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using RocksDB for caching frequently asked query results from Mongo is a key to good application caching.

If we are asking about weather in Limerick, Warsaw and Moscow - it is faster to store query with it's result in key-value DB and retrieve on demand (having a TTL flag set) instead of hammering mongo with same queries.

Answer (score 5):

RocksDB is an key value store which can be used as a storage engine component in many database systems. [Mongo rocks](https://github.com/mongodb-partners/mongo-rocks) is a version of MongoDB which uses rocksdb as storage engine . So consider it as a storage engine similar to [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) for MySQL. Infact, there is a branch of MySQL which uses RocksDB as a storage engine which is called [MyRocks](https://github.com/facebook/mysql-5.6/wiki/Getting-Started-with-MyRocks).